# Media player for Windows Embedded Compact 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, operating-system, windows-ce

Is there any media player which supports the video formats like wmv,avi,asf,mpeg4,msrle,mpeg1, mpeg2 etc for WEC7.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the media player is already available and can be enabled through catalog items, when required.

Please check through the following [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg158347%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx) for the catalog items and sysgen variables required for enabling it.